# Android tutorial (first) app crashed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Stuck on [myfirstapp tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).
So, app crashed after button was clicked.
There are a few answered question here(stackoverflow) but in my case error is:
"Unable to find explicit activity class {com.murr.mid.clanscript/com.mid.test.MainActivity$DisplayMessageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Can't get it, why it ask for MainActivity$DisplayMessageActivity ?

More code:

> public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity. Method binded to button onClick

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String msg = et.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MSG, msg);
    startActivity(intent);
}


//public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MSG);
}
```

Comment: hmmm http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html ... activity classes should not be nested ... (ok they can ... but then they should be public static ... and name in manifest should be `.MainActivity$DisplayMessageActivity`)

Comment: Where are you declaring DisplayMessageActivity??? same file or separate file?

Comment: separated http://puu.sh/eJCAV/3d3543c360.png

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining a package in your manifest making it unable to find your MainActivity class.

Read about [Android Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) here, specially the `Defining Class Names` paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your AndroidManifest.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.murr.mid.clanscript" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks to [Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) and his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28027594/android-tutorial-first-app-crashed#comment44440350_28027594) to my question.
So, I have a bad habit to play around tutorial and run the code before read to the end.

In the tutorial we have a code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
```

and this code generates error, because we have no DisplayMessageActivity defined yet. I add this class to MainActivity file. And forgot about it.
Do not do like me. Read tutorials to the end :)
Thank for your attention, guys.